# mongoose 7.0.3 how to update subdocument with not strict schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents with subdocuments. In general, schema looks like this:

```
const CurrentState = {
    NameOfProduct: { type: String },
    ResearcherName: { type: String },
    CollectedDate: { type: String },
    Url: { type: String },
    AuditNumber: { type: Number },
    ImageLinks: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed},
    start_date: { type: Date },
    currency_to: { type: String } // originally not in schema
};

const Product = new mongoose.Schema({
    RecordId: { type: Number },
    CurrentState: { type: CurrentState, strict: false },
}, { strict: false, versionKey: false, minimize: false});
```

The CurrentState schema contains only obligatory fields but also can contain other fields not included in the schema. Because in Product schema it used with `strict: false`, when I do querying I am getting all fields. The problems are arising when I am trying to update this not obligatory field (for example the field `currency_to`).
What I do:

```
// getting the document
let doc = productSchema.findOne(RecordId);
// change value of field  currency_to
doc.CurrentState.currency_to = 'newValue'
// save changes
await doc.updateOne(doc).exec();
```

Firstly, I see that the assignment of the 'newValue' didn't work, `doc.CurrentState.currency_to` still contains the old value.
Secondly, with the enabled debug option in Mongoose I see that `updateOne` executes with only those fields in the schema. And as a result, all not obligatory fields are getting lost. When I insert  `currency_to: { type: String }`  into the schema it's saved as expected. But I don't want to put all my not obligatory fields into schema there are lots of them. So what should I do? How can I update the field currency_to in this case?

It worked in 5th version of Mongoose. I've got this problem updating Mongoose to 7.0.3 version.

And one more point to add. I don't want to use operator $set. It would make my code more complicated. I want to work with a document as with an object. Is it still possible in new version?

Comment: I think you have to define CurrentState as a Schema and set `strict: false` for that schema, rather than just defining `strict: false`, when using in product schema.

Comment: I've tried this. It solves only half of the problem. The fields aren't getting lost but I am still unable to change the value of currency_to. I can change it only when I am putting it into schema.

Comment: Rather than directly changing the value, try to use `set` method on the `doc`, like this: `doc.set('CurrentState.currency_to',  'newValue', { strict: false})`

Comment: Yes I can do that. But question still is I want to work with a document as with an object. Is it still possible in new version?

Comment: I think I got the error, you are calling `updateOne` function on the `doc`, and then you are passing `doc` to it, whereas it expects a MongoDB update document, with operators and everything. Since you're already, setting properties via assignments, use the `save` function on the `doc`, like `doc.save()`

Comment: `doc.save() ` not works. It saves unchanged value of `'CurrentState.currency_to'`.  I think problem here not in saving but in assigment. Looks like there no possibility to change the field not presented in schema by direct assigment.

Comment: yeah, that's the case most likely.